# Add escape "\" in front of special character for a string

Tags: java, string, special-characters

I have a simple SQL query where I check whether the query matches any of the fields I have. I'm using LIKE statement for this. One of my field can have special characters and so does the search query. So I'm looking for a solution where I need to an escape "\" in front of the special character.

```
query = "hello+Search}query"
```

I need the above to change to

```
query = "hello\+Search\}query"
```

Is there a simple way of doing this other than searching for each special character separately and adding the "\". Because if I don't have the escape character I will get the error message

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' near index 0
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What context are you using it in?  Why do you use it in a regex? Can you show the context where that error is happening (please edit the question).

Comment: Also please add what database you are using.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Decide which special characters you want to escape and just call

```
query.replace("}", "\\}")
```

You may keep all special characters you allow in some array then iterate it and replace the occurrences as exemplified.
This method replaces all [regex meta characters](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Regular_expressions_1__Special_characters.html).

```
public String escapeMetaCharacters(String inputString){
    final String[] metaCharacters = {"\\","^","$","{","}","[","]","(",")",".","*","+","?","|","<",">","-","&","%"};

    for (int i = 0 ; i < metaCharacters.length ; i++){
        if(inputString.contains(metaCharacters[i])){
            inputString = inputString.replace(metaCharacters[i],"\\"+metaCharacters[i]);
        }
    }
    return inputString;
}
```

You could use it as `query=escapeMetaCharacters(query);`
Don't think that any library you would find would do anything more than that. At best it defines a complete list of specialCharacters.

Comment: OP said "other than searching for each special character separately and adding the \".

Comment: Indeed, but there is no better option. I recommend he just keeps track of all special characters he escapes.

Comment: You need to init outputString to inputString and not to an empty String, in case no special characters exists

Comment: Still need this kind of workaround in Java in 2018 :(

Answer (score 7):

There is actually a better way of doing this in a sleek manner.

```
String REGEX = "[\\[+\\]+:{}^~?\\\\/()><=\"!]";

StringUtils.replaceAll(inputString, REGEX, "\\\\$0");
```

Comment: This method is deprecated in newer versions of commons-lang3 ( my version is 3.12.0 )

Comment: commons lang methods is just a null safe replacement for inbuilt string method `String.replaceAll()`. `inputString.replaceAll(REGEX, "\\\\$0")` would work too if you ensure `inputString` is not null.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `\\` to introduce a `\` into a string literal; that is you need to *escape* the `\`. (A single backslash is used to introduce special characters into a string: e.g. `\t` is a tab.)

`query = "hello\\+Search\\}query"` is what you need.

Comment: ok, but either way, I need a way to identify the location of the special character such as "+", so I would be able to add that value. My query looks like this "hello+Search}query" I need to find the special characters location to add the escape character.

Comment: Simply replace `+` with `\\+`, etc.

Comment: Or use a prepared statement. It should also be able to handle these special characters.

Comment: I need a generic method to identify all the special characters in my query, "+" was an example. So I was looking for a solution which is more elegant than looking for each special character and replace it.

Comment: @Tom: I agree. Sadly, the OP has not specified the database.

Comment: @Visahan there isn't a more elegant solution. If you find a library/class that does that, inside you will find a function similar to what i provided.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do same thing in javascript. I came up with below solution. I think it might help someone.

```
function escapeSpecialCharacters(s){
 let arr = s.split('');
 arr = arr.map(function(d){
         return d.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\'+d)
       });
 let reg = new RegExp(arr.join('')); 
 return reg;
}

let newstring = escapeSpecialCharacters("hello+Search}query");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Java 8+ and Streams, you could do something like:

```java
private String escapeSpecialCharacters(String input) {
    List<String> specialCharacters = Lists.newArrayList("\\","^","$","{","}","[","]","(",")",".","*","+","?","|","<",">","-","&","%");
    return Arrays.stream(input.split("")).map((c) -> {
                if (specialCharacters.contains(c)) return "\\" + c;
                else return c;
    }).collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple version ( without deprecated `StringUtils.replaceAll` ):

```
    String regex = "[\\[+\\]+:{}^~?\\\\/()><=\"!]";
    String query = "hello+Search}query";
    String replaceAll = query.replaceAll(regex, "\\\\$0");
```